# Cannot remove ValueEventListener set for single value and no timeout in Firebase DB

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

When using addListenerForSingleValueEvent it would be nice to add timeout to this operation.  As Firebase seems to lack this, I thought I would implement it on my own.  However, I've discovered I'm unable to remove these listeners.  Calling removeEventListener doesn't do the job.  They still get triggered whenever Firebase achieves connection to server.  It is possible handle this logically inside onDataChanged but this gets very very complex when these events fire unexpectedly and completely out of context..  Anybody know of a clean way to deal with this?

Code:  I set and remove the listener immediately.  Sometime later turn on internet - onDataChanged is called.

```
        DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("blablalba");
        oneshotlistener = new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                Log.v("FIREBASE LISTEN", "ONE SHOT LISTENER TRIGGERED");
                if (snapshot.exists())
                {
                    String s = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Log.v("FIREBASE LISTEN", "RESULT: " + s);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error)
            {
                Log.v("LISTEN", "DB FAIL");
            }
        };
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(oneshotlistener);
        ref.removeEventListener(oneshotlistener);   //remove immediately for test
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick examination of addListenerForSingleValueEvent code reveals why this fails:

Firebase adds its own eventlistener that is removed when onDataChanged is called. So there is nothing special about addListenerForSingleValueEvent and I assume we can get around the problem this way (using the regular addValueEventListener):

```
DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("blabla");
        oneshotlistener = new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                snapshot.getRef().removeEventListener(this);
                Log.v("FIREBASE LISTEN", "ONE SHOT LISTENER TRIGGERED");
                if (snapshot.exists())
                {
                    String s = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Log.v("FIREBASE LISTEN", "RESULT: " + s);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error)
            {
                Log.v("LISTEN", "DB FAIL");
            }
        };
        ref.addValueEventListener(oneshotlistener);
        ref.removeEventListener(oneshotlistener);    //remove immediately for test
```

Tests confirm the listener is never triggered. Now a timeout routine can be developed to remove the listener and raise an error. Also the listener can be removed in onPause() so no unexpected onDataChanged events are raised if the app is paused/resumed.
Still, it would be nice if Firebase had this feature built-in.  Have a function that allows setting listen timeout in milliseconds and for listeners that are registered with addListenerForSingleValueEvent have an additional interface call like:

```
        db.setTimeout(ms);

        DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("blablalba");
        oneshotlistener = new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                Log.v("FIREBASE LISTEN", "ONE SHOT LISTENER TRIGGERED");
                if (snapshot.exists())
                {
                    String s = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Log.v("FIREBASE LISTEN", "RESULT: " + s);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error)
            {
                Log.v("LISTEN", "DB FAIL");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTimeout()
            {
                Log.v("LISTEN", "OP TIMEDOUT");
                //take action
            }
        };
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(oneshotlistener);
```